# unity2d Problem With local positioning of child with rotating parent

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game, in which I have clouds that when shot are hidden using sprite masks, the sprite masks are then attached to the cloud via parenting, here is the function that attaches and positions the masks.

```
    public void SpawnGasCloudMask(Transform collisionTransform, Vector2 difference)
    {
        GasCloudMaskController selectedGasCloudMask = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < gasCloudMaskList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!gasCloudMaskList[i].gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                selectedGasCloudMask = gasCloudMaskList[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if(selectedGasCloudMask == null)
        {
            selectedGasCloudMask = InstantiateGasCloudMaskController();
        }
        selectedGasCloudMask.transform.SetParent(collisionTransform);
        float angle = collisionTransform.rotation.z;
        Vector2 straightPosition = new Vector2(difference.x / collisionTransform.localScale.x, difference.y / collisionTransform.localScale.y);
        selectedGasCloudMask.transform.localPosition = straightPosition;
        
        selectedGasCloudMask.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wzdu.jpg)

This is the result when the cloud is not rotated, However if I rotate it, say 90 degrees.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxdH7.jpg)

I have tried using RotateAroundLocal, but it is said to be deprecated and I cannot see it having an effect. Obviously what I want is for the masks to be properly attached to the parent based on its rotation, I tried doing some geometry, but solving this remains yet out of my reach. I believe I have to change its local parameter position, I did manage to do it with non parented gameObject, however the local parameter does not offer the RotateAround function. I will appreciate any help.TY.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer:

```
selectedGasCloudMask.transform.RotateAround(collisionTransform.position,
    -collisionTransform.forward, collisionTransform.eulerAngles.z);
```

Since the position to which the child attaches to the parent, you need to account for the parent's rotation. The deprecate function that did exactly that was replaced by the generic function, which requires you to understand what is going on.